# How to replace one value from a column

Tags: sql

I have a script that pulls a column and some of the cells have nothing so they are returned with a 'dash'. I want these to be replaced with 'Global' but have all the other results retrieved. I don't want to specify each one in a case as they can change from time to time.

Comment: What is the actual value in these columns (it's hard to tell from your question)? Is it a "-", an empty string or `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN MyColumn = '-' THEN 'Global' 
     ELSE MyColumn
END 
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: "I don't want to specify each one in a case as they can change from time to time."  From my understanding, your answer is not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, have a lookup table.  Something like

```
create table ConfigTable
(
    pkConfigTable int identity(1, 1) not null primary key clustered,
    ConfigKey varchar(100) not null,
    ConfigValue varchar(100) not null
)
go

insert into ConfigTable
values('NothingString', '-')
go

declare @NullChar varchar(10)
go

select @NullChar = ConfigValue
from ConfigTable
where ConfigKey = 'NothingString'
go

select
    case 
        when yourColumnToTest = @NullChar
            then 'Global'
        else yourColumnToTest
    end
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `IF` could possibly do:

```
SELECT
 IF(Column = '-', 'Global', Column) AS NiceNameForColumn
FROM
 Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(a_column, '-'), 'Global') AS a_column_narrative
  FROM YourTable;
```